# How to align all the phrases one below the other, from the one that repeats itself most often to the one that repeats the least?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How to align all the phrases one below the other, from the one that repeats itself most often to the one that repeats the least?

I have this : "to do,2,can you,5,do you,4"

I want this : to do 2,
              can you 2,
              do you 4,

```
function toPhrases(text, wordCount) {
const words = text.match(/[\w\u0402-\u045f]+/ig);
const phrases = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let
        phrase = words.slice(i, i + wordCount).join(' '),
        hashedPhrases = phrases.get(phrase);
    if (hashedPhrases) {
        phrases.set(phrase, hashedPhrases + 1);
    } else {
        phrases.set(phrase, 1);
    }
    if (i + wordCount >= words.length) {
        break;
    }
}
// Each member of phrases is actually a two-element array like [phrase, count], so...
let duplicatePhrases = [...phrases].filter(phrase => phrase[1] > 1);
return duplicatePhrases;
```

}

function createPhrases() {
    const text = document.getElementById('textarea').value;

```
document.getElementById('output-2').innerHTML = toPhrases(text.toString(), 2);
document.getElementById('output-3').innerHTML = toPhrases(text.toString(), 3);
document.getElementById('output-4').innerHTML = toPhrases(text.toString(), 4);
```

}

Comment: Fiddle/snippet please.

Comment: what is repeating itself?

Comment: I think this 
to do 5,
can you 4,
do you 3,

Comment: what does it mean? what is the meaning of the numbers? and what are you refering to with the repeating term?

Comment: Numbers are frequency of phrase in text.

Comment: but what is a phrase in this context? please add some clear examples and the wanted results.

Comment: The function extracts phrases from the text, the problem is that it writes the result (phrases) side by side, not one below the other.

Comment: Chack this . https://codepen.io/drago-ivan/project/editor/AKWbJQ